# Dojo.hitch immediately-called: Confirming my suspicions

Tags: javascript, dojo

This is probably a quick one. From what I understand, the `dojo.hitch()` function is useful for giving you a function callback that will always be called in the namespace you need (the first argument). However, I've seen a number of calling syntaxes like the following:

```
dojo.hitch(iamanamespace, iamanamespace.doSomething)();
```

The part that weirds me out is the two parentheses at the end. They're apparently not creating this function for later - they're just calling it right now. My obvious thought is that this could be shortened to:

```
iamanamespace.doSomething();
```

I was just sort of doing this replacement absent-mindedly, thinking it was the result of someone being over-careful with `this` references, but then I found that I was able to locate a few instances of this in the "dojox" modules, and even one inside of dojo/_base/lang that did change the namespace context, but still could have just used "`.call()`".

Can I just confirm with anyone who's used dojo for a while what situation, if any, might demand the use of a hitch to be called immediately, as opposed to doing it the normal, old-fashioned way?

Comment: Could you please point to those few places? I only found some in the inline docs to `hitch`.

Comment: @Bergi dojox/atom/widget/FeedEntryEditor:514,948, dojox/drawing/annotations/Label:39. Also less egregious in dijit/_WidgetBase:1120. I used this regex to find them: "hitch\([^\)]+\)\(\)"

Comment: Yeah, those in the `FeedEntryEditor` and `Label` really seem useless. The `WidgetBase` one might profit from accepting strings for `fcn`, even though it is not documented.

Comment: Argh, here it is in S.E. code: `hitch\([^\)]+\)\(\)`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Dojo, but from looking at [the source](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/_base/lang.js#L331) I can tell you that you're right. When you know the arguments, you should shorten the call.

There might be one reason only to use `hitch` though: If you want to allow both functions and method names it might be shorter to immediately-invoke a hitched function than to write something like

```
if (typeof fn == "string")
    fn = (context || global)[fn];
if (typof fn == "function")
    fn.call(context);
else
    throw "not a function";
```

Comment: Thanks; hadn't considered that instance if someone were calling with `(myModule, myModule.nameOfIntendedCallbackFunction)`.